# How to make dynamic attributes in Yii2 like in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, yii2

In Laravel I can write

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    public function getTextAttribute($value) {
        return strtoupper($value);
    }
}
```

And then

```
$model = MyModel::find(1);
$model->text = 'test';
echo $model->text; // returns 'TEXT'
```

Can I do similar in Yii2?

Comment: Both Laravel and Yii2 are written in PHP. You may use a step-by-step debugger to explore a part of the code that executes `$model->text` in Laravel and then copy that PHP sample to Yii2. Not easy, but it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public var in your MyModel and you  can redifine the text getter  this way

```
class MyModel extends Model {

    public $text;

    public function getText() {
        return strtoupper($this->text);
    }
}
```

.

```
 $model= MyModel::findOne(1);
 $model->text =  'test';
 echo $model->text;
```